# Merge two tables into a single indexed view in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, indexing, view

So here is my dilemma, I'm currently storing all my records into a giant flat table that has movies, episodes, series, games etc. 70% of the records are episodes that I do NOT want indexed by the default full-text catalog as they make up over 2 million of the records and 90% of the time people are searching for movies/series, so I want to move these records into a separate table so they can have their own separate full-text catalog and a few additional columns that do not apply to movies/series (season, episode # etc.) as well.

My issue is with stored procedure I use to checkTable if an ID already exists before I go and download data or update data for that ID.

I wanted to create a view of all the ID's across both tables so I could lookup in a single place if that ID exists, however when I try to union the tables it will not allow me to create an index on the view.

```
ID          Type      |     ID          Type
1           movie     |     2           episode
3           movie     |     4           episode
5           movie     |     6           episode
```

The ID's are unique and will never have duplicates in either table.

I feel that since this view will have over 2 million records an indexed might be important being it is called over 250-500+ a second so optimization is a huge factor.

Is there a better approach than using UNION ALL to get ID's 1,2,3,4,5,6 into a single view?

Comment: One "hack" someone suggested was create a second view of the unioned view and place my index on that...

Comment: You can't put an index on a view that selects from a view that isn't indexed, so I don't think that would work.

Comment: @TabAlleman Well that's annoying! I guess my only option is to lookup the ID in both tables every time.

Comment: Maybe you could CROSS JOIN the tables and COALESCE the columns; I don't know if that's allowed in an indexed view or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your best solution is to create a view that does UNION ALL of the two tables, but instead of trying to index the view, make sure you have a good indexing strategy implemented on the tables themselves.

You can use Index Hints in your view to force the view to use those indexes whenever someone selects from the view.

Comment: The main index on both tables is the ID (int) column but it's also a clustered index that I have to rebuild/optimize manually every other day.

Comment: You want an index that covers the columns most often used as sargs in queries on the view.   If that's ID, then you're already set.   You probably wouldn't get much better performance from an indexed view.   If a particular query is running slow, check the execution plan and see if the indexes are being used, or if you're getting table scans.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with hints, there is another view I lookup with a NOEXPAND hint that shows me a total count of records updated by date... Without that NOEXPAND the lookup was VERY slow.